# Extract indices of a dataframe based on a values (provided as an array) from a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array as: `df1.values = array([1,2,3,4])`. 
Now, I want to get the indices of `df2` where `df2.x` has the values from `df1.values`. So for instance, if `df2.x.values= [1,3,4,2,5,6]`, then I want the return to be `1,4,2,3` which are index values of df2 where the values from df1 can be found.

I looked everywhere on stackoverflow and was not able to find how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4],columns=['x'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1,3,4,2,5,6],columns=['x'])

df2['old_index']=df2.index.values
df2.set_index('x').loc[df1['x']]['old_index'].values
```

Basically, we extract the values of the original index of `df2` (these are the return values that you want) as a new column, set the `x` column as a new index using `.set_index` (assuming you don't have any missing or duplicate values), and get your return values based on the new index.